# Immutability of tuples in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

We know that tuple is immutable in Python. Then why the below code works?

```
3 * ('a','b','c')
```

> Gives output as below:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: It creates a *new* tuple leaving the existing one unchanged, `3 * [1,2]` also creates a new list (this is  how `__rmul__` is implemented for custom classes too, regardless of mutability), what do you struggle with?

Comment: Numbers are also immutable, yet you can `x = 5` then `x * 3` and get 15. Tuples are the same.

Comment: BTW a slightly more interesting question is why does `tup *= 3` work, of course this is also intended and documented

Answer (score 4):

You created a new tuple, see how `id`s differ:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> id(a)
4505615456
>>> b = a * 3
>>> id(b)
4504578232
```

However, what you've accomplished will create also a new list if you did the equivalent:

```
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
>>> id(a)
4505618120
>>> b = a * 3
>>> id(b)
4505618248
```

You can see the list is mutable with the following code:

```
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
4505618568
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a.append(2)
>>> a.append(3)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
4505618568
```

You can't achieve the same with a tuple.

One last thing to convince yourself that tuples are immutable:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[0] = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
```

versus the equivalent with a list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[0] = 10
>>> a
[10, 2, 3]
```

For more info and pitfalls, see this interesting article http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/10/python-tuples-immutable-but-potentially-changing.html

Answer (score 1):

"Immutable" means "Can't be modified," not "Can't be used to construct other data." The latter wouldn't make much sense in a container, anyway! What use is there of a tuple other than containing data for later use?

Your sample code `3 * ('a', 'b', 'c') = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')` just shows that multiplying a tuple by a scalar creates a new tuple with duplicating elements. The following is NOT possible however:

```
tup = ('a', 'b', 'c')
tup[0] = 'z'  # fails, because tuples are not mutable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`('a','b','c')` is a tuple.
```

And `3 * ('a','b','c')=('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')` is another tuple which is made of 3 times of `('a','b','c')`.
If you think `x =('a','b','c')` then `3*('a','b','c')` = x+x+x` (look, x and x+x+x is not same!).Both of them are separate tuples. 
In this similar rule 1 and 1+1+1 are not same!

You will find a proof in Benjamin Toueg's answer.